# jQuery how display as variables in text fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my JavaScript function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    (function($) {
        $.fn.calculateMortgage = function(options) {
            var defaults = {
                params: {}
            };
            var calculate = function(params) {
                params = $.extend({
                    benzyna: 0,
                    gaz: 0,
                    sp_benz: 0,
                    przebieg: 0,
                    cena_inst: 0
                }, params);
                var N = params.benzyna * params.sp_benz;
                var I = (+(params.sp_benz * 0.15)) + (+(params.sp_benz));
                var J = params.gaz * I;
                var K = (((params.cena_inst) / (N - J)) * 100);
                var L = params.przebieg / 12;
                var L1 = K / L;
                var M = (L / 100 * (N - J));

                var R = (M * 12);
                var result = N;
                return result;
            };
            return this.each(function() {
                var $element = $(this);
                var $result = calculate(options.params);
                var output = '<p> koszt przejazdu na 100km = ' + $result.toFixed(2) + '</p>';
                $(output).appendTo($element);
            });
        };
    })(jQuery);
    $(function() {
        $('#test').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $params = {
                benzyna: $('#benzyna').val(),
                gaz: $('#gaz').val(),
                sp_benz: $('#sp_benz').val(),
                przebieg: $('#przebieg').val(),
                cena_inst: $('#cena_inst').val()
            };
            $(this).calculateMortgage({
                params: $params
            })
        });
    });
});
```

And this is code when I use visible value

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-xs-5 col-sm-4" for="exampleInputEmail1"> 100km</label>
                <input class="col-xs-5 col-sm-4" type="text" id="exampleInputEmail1"
                    class="form-control" placeholder=" ">
                <label class ="col-xs-2 col-sm-4" for="exampleInputEmail1"> ...</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I want to display the values of individual variables in separate text boxes. Such as the Internet helped me to get variables from a text field and perform operations on them. But now I have to show them in the appropriate fields of the form. How to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use like this:

```
 suppose 

 <input id="my_input"></input>
```

jquery code:

```
$('#my_iput').val(your value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the val property of inputs to put text in them.

```
 $("#INPUTID").val(YOURTEXT)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set the values of input fields like this:

```
$("#id_of_Input").val(your text here);
```

so try using `id` to `identify` the input fields uniquely to set values.